# disable a hyperlink using jQuery

Tags: jquery, disable-link

```
<a href="gohere.aspx" class="my-link">Click me</a>
```

I did

```
$('.my-link').attr('disabled', true);
```

but it didn't work

Is there an easy way to disable the hyperlink using jquery? Remove href? I would rather not fiddle with href. So if I can do it w/o removing href, that would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically enable/disable links with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788946/how-do-i-dynamically-enable-disable-links-with-jquery)

Answer (score 126):

You can bind a click handler that returns false:

```
$('.my-link').click(function () {return false;});
```

To re-enable it again, unbind the handler:

```
$('.my-link').unbind('click');
```

Note that `disabled` doesn't work because it is designed for form inputs only.

---

jQuery has anticipated this already, providing a shortcut as of jQuery 1.4.3:

```
$('.my-link').bind('click', false);
```

And to unbind / re-enable:

```
$('.my-link').unbind('click', false);
```

Comment: With 1.4.3 or later, you can shorten it a bit with `$('.my-link').bind('click',false);`.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, `bind()` and `unbind()` have been replaced with `on()` and `off()`. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) for more info.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17935158/2218697) post has **easiest way using bootstrap**, hope helps.

Answer (score 32):

I know it's an old question but it seems unsolved still. Follows my solution...

Simply add this global handler:

```
$('a').click(function()
{
     return ($(this).attr('disabled')) ? false : true;
});
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/akihik/3

you can even add a bit of css to give a different style to all the links with the disabled attribute.

e.g

```
a[disabled]
{
    color: grey; 
}
```

Anyway it seems that the disabled attribute is not valid for `a` tags. If you prefer to follow the w3c specs you can easily adopt an html5 compliant `data-disabled` attribute. In this case you have to modify the previous snippet and use `$(this).data('disabled')`.

Comment: I think this should actually be: if ($(this).attr('disabled')) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); }

Comment: Also, to ensure that dynamically added anchors are also disabled, the full code should be: $("body").on("click", "a", function (e) { if ($(this).attr('disabled')) { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } });

Comment: (can't edit comment after 5 mins). I forgot to add: e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 12):

Removing the `href` attribute definitely seems to the way to go. If for some reason you need it later, I would just store it in another attribute, e.g.

```
$(".my-link").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-oldhref", $(this).attr("href"));
    $(this).removeAttr("href");
});
```

This is the only way to do it that will make the link appear disabled as well without writing custom CSS. Just binding a click handler to false will make the link appear like a normal link, but nothing will happen when clicking on it, which may be confusing to users. If you are going to go the click handler route, I would at least also `.addClass("link-disabled")` and write some CSS that makes links with that class appear like normal text.

Comment: removing the `href` will also mess up SEO rankings. leaving the attribute and disabling it will make robots realise it is a link.

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.my-link').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

You could use:

```
$('.my-link').click(function(e) { return false; });
```

But I don't like to use this myself as it is more cryptic, even though it is used extensively throughout much jQuery code.

Answer (score 7):

The `pointer-events` CSS property is a little lacking when it comes to support ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events)), but it's very succinct:

```
.my-link { pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: But this can also disable any other work the link does. For example, the hover won't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
function EnableHyperLink(id) {
        $('#' + id).attr('onclick', 'Pagination("' + id + '")');//onclick event which u 
        $('#' + id).addClass('enable-link');
        $('#' + id).removeClass('disable-link');
    }

    function DisableHyperLink(id) {
        $('#' + id).addClass('disable-link');
        $('#' + id).removeClass('enable-link');
        $('#' + id).removeAttr('onclick');
    }

.disable-link
{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: black !important;
    cursor: default;
}
.enable-link
{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    color: #075798 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `disabled` attribute isn't valid on all HTML elements I believe, see the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That and the proper value for disabled is simply "disabled". Your best approach is to bind a click function that returns false.

Comment: This is the first time I see somebody reference MSDN, W3C link please?!

Comment: @Zappa, w3School is not related to W3C. W3C is www.w3.org

Answer (score 2):

Append a class containing pointer-events:non

```
.active a{ //css
text-decoration: underline;
background-color: #fff;
pointer-events: none;}


$(this).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Below will replace the link with it's text

```
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

**Edit :**

Above given code will work with hyperlinks with text only, it will not work with images. When we'll try it with image link it won't show any image.

To make this code compatible with image links following will work fine

```
// below given function will replace links with images i.e. for image links
$('a img').each(function () {
    var image = this.src;
    var img = $('<img>', { src: image });
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(img);
});

// This piece of code will replace links with its text i.e. for text links
$('a').each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

**explanation :** In above given code snippets, in first snippet we are replacing all the image links with it's images only. After that we are replacing text links with it's text.

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me from having to edit 2400 chunks of text... or learn regexes (and who wants to do that, right?).

Comment: How can I set the link back to its default? suppose I disabled all the links with $(this).replaceWith($(this).text()); but how can I set it to its enabled default?

Answer (score 0):

This also works well. Is simple, lite, and doesn't require jQuery to be used.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
$(this).prop( "disabled", true );
```

Comment: "disabled" is not available on links.  Might work in IE, but not other browsers.