# What is the correct way to re-enable an ASP.NET LinkButton after disabling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, linkbutton

I have searched for two days now to find a solution to this problem and I can't seem to find anything that works for me. I have a `LinkButton` that is disabled when the page loads. I am disabling the button like this:

```
$("#BtnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
$("#BtnSubmit").removeAttr("enabled");
```

When the user fills out all of the required fields, I am attempting to re-enable the `LinkButton` like this:

```
 $("#BtnSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
```

However, this does not work. I have looked at the generated markup, and it seems that the `LinkButton` has its `href` attribute removed when it is set to `disabled`. Simply removing the `disabled` attribute does not work. I have also tried adding the `enabled` attribute like this:

```
$("#BtnSubmit").attr("enabled", "true");
```

However, this doesn't work either.

What am I missing? The button is clearly being re-enabled from a design perspective. It goes from its `disabled` appearance to its `enabled` appearance just fine, but it doesn't get its `href` attribute back. I've tried manually adding the `href`, but that also doesn't work. Most of the solutions I've found just cover how to disable the button; none of them seem to mention anything about re-enabling it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggling enabled/disabled state of a LinkButton using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13163923/123422)

Comment: @PaulAbbott I am trying out that solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It'd be good if you could provide us with your ASPX markup and its code behind in your post. There are many ways to disable/enable the button. Did you do it from via the server-side or client-side? My hunch is that you probably set `Enabled` property on your LinkButton to `False`, which explains why the `href` attribute was gone as well.

One approach you could consider is that you can register your client-side javascript code in `Page_Load` event, and when page reloads, the code will then be executed.

Something like this

```
var script = "$('#BtnSubmit').prop('disabled', true);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, GetType(), "mykey", "script", true);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, not long ago. This worked for me:

```
    $("#BtnSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#BtnSubmit").prop("disabled", false);
```

Note that the HTML property was set like this on page load:

```
<input type="submit" id="BtnSubmit" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: I tried this, but, unfortunately, it didn't work. I had the same problems as before.