# how to disable one hyperlink by clicking on second hyperlink

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have 2 hyperlinks. 
when i click on one hyperlink the another hyperlink should be disabled means it should be seen but not clicked by any user

Please help me

```
 <a href="">hiii </a> 
 <a id="check" href="google.com">bye</a>
```

in  JavaScript

```
$('#check').attr('disabled', true);
```

but it is not working

Comment: `shoud be seen, but not clicked by any user` ==> please, explain, you only want to disable link or change its href?

Comment: I want to disable it means it should not been click my any other user

Answer (score 4):

Using java script you can disable the hyper link by adding a .disabled class as seen below:

```
  .inactive //add this class to the link if you want to disable it 
{
    pointer-events: none;// this will disable the link
    cursor:default;
}
```

then use .inactive class in appropriate line...

Answer (score 3):

Try below

```
$('.my-link').click(function () {return false;});
```

To re-enable it again, unbind the handler:

```
$('.my-link').unbind('click');
```

or

```
$('.my-link').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Use this to re-enable it:

```
$('.my-link').attr('disabled', '');
```

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 3):

Below is the code you need.

```
<a id="gLink" href="http://google.com">click me</a><br />
<a onclick="disableLink()" href="#">Disable link</a><br />
<a onclick="enableLink()" href="#">Enable link</a>
```

javsacript functions:

```
 function disableLink() {
        var a = document.getElementById('gLink');
        a.href = "#";
    }

    function enableLink() {
        var a = document.getElementById('gLink');
        a.href = "http://google.com";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

for e.g if you have

```
  <a id="link1" href="page1.php">One</a> <a id="link2" href="page2.php">Two</a>

document.getElementById('link1').onclick = function()
 {
   document.getElementById('link1').disabled = true;
   document.getElementById('link2').disabled = false;
 };

  document.getElementById('link2').onclick = function()
 {
   document.getElementById('link1').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('link2').disabled = true;
 };
```

Comment: you have to create another function as well forlink2                      document.getElementById('link2').onclick = function()
 {
   document.getElementById('link1').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('link2').disabled = true;
 };

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery onClick event (or .on("click") / .live("onClick") or whatever you prefer) to change to attribute of the link like this:

```
$('.my-link').attr('disabled', true);
```

Short example:

```
<a href='#' id='link1'>First</a>
<a href='#' id='link2'>Second</a>
<script>
    $("#link2").onClick(function(){
        $('#link1').attr('disabled', true);
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: whether disbaled will work for that ?  see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085584/disable-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Comment: I've added an example.. Haven't checked for typos/syntax but you get the point ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed that. You can't redirect if you want to disable the link. Retest it please.

Answer (score 0):

That's all I know

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = firstLoad;
  function firstLoad() {
  document.getElementById("lesson").href = "";
   document.getElementById("posttest").href = "";
   }
     function clickHome() {
    document.getElementById("pretest").href = "";
     document.getElementById("lesson").href = "lesson.html";
    }
     function lessonRead() {
      document.getElementById("posttest").href = "posttest.html";
     document.getElementById("lesson").href = "";
       }
     </script>
         </head>
    <body>
      <a href="home.html" id="home" onClick="clickHome()">Home</a> | 
     <a href="pre-test.html" id="pretest">Pre-test</a> | 
     <a href="lesson.html" id="lesson">Lesson</a> | 
     <a href="post-test.html" id="posttest" onClick="lessonRead()">Post-test</a> | 
     <a href="about.html" id="about">About</a> | 
     </body>
     </html>
```