# Avoid jQuery click function on <a href=""> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I do have the following click function on a div element. Inside the div element are  links. How can I stop the click function on this links? I tried z-index but it doesn't work.

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function () {
 if ($(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').hasClass('flipIt')) {
     $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').removeClass('flipIt');
 } else {
     $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').addClass('flipIt');
 }
});
```

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085584/disable-a-hyperlink-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add code to stop the click from propagating from the links up the DOM to the div:

```
$('a').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XCdyU/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try `e.preventDefault()`

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').hasClass('flipIt')) {
        $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').removeClass('flipIt');
    } else {
        $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').addClass('flipIt');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Capture the event object:

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function (evt) {
```

Test to see what sort of element was clicked:

```
if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouse down event and in your handler call event.stopPropagation() and event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

if click target is an `a` just return false else do normal stuff...

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

`z-index` won't do anything, however if you want to prevent clicks from css you can add `pointer-events` property to links and set the value `none`. That will disable all kind of events on links.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.thumb.flip').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName==="A") {  //if target is an anchor, ignore
        return;
    }
    $(this).find('.thumb-wrapper').toggleClass('flipIt')  //toggle class
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit markup do this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ></a>
```