# How to disable a Font-Awesome button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

How do I disable a font-awesome button in jQuery?

```
<a id="btnOK" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> OK
</a>
```

jQuery is not disabling this button when I try this:

```
$("#btnOK").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Here you may find your answer 
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085584/disable-a-hyperlink-using-jquery
   Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<button id="btnOK" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> OK
</button>

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Ready");
    $("#btnOK").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    $("#btnOK").click(function(){
        alert("Ok clicked");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ureyzea1/

Comment: Its works. Also with hypelink same work with AddClass $("#btnOK").addClass('disabled');