# ng-disabled not working with <i> tag using font-awesome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, font-awesome, angularjs-ng-disabled

I have created a plunk in which I want to validate a form that has a button created using font-awesome.
The text field is required and I want to disabled the icon if no data is entered.But `ng-disabled` dosen't seem to support this functionality with font awesome icon.
Has anyone faced this issue before.Please share your thoughts..

Please find the plunk [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rHRFLP?p=preview)

Comment: For your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891858/how-to-disable-a-font-awesome-button-in-jquery

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place it inside a button and it should work:

```
    <button ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid" ng-click="$ctrl.checkIfClicked()">
      <i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
```

You can format the style of the button in a way you want.

Answer (score 0):

In file css you can add

> .disabled {   cursor: not-allowed; }

And in html file, you change

```
<i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-2x" ng-class="{disabled: testForm.$invalid}" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="$ctrl.checkIfClicked()"></i>
```

Comment: but still you will be able to click the button.Right?

Comment: yes i tried and icon is clickable and also shows blocked icon on hover

Comment: this solution we cant use