# Disable click event with jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, anchor, event-binding

My question is related about disabling links/click events with jQuery, and it's probably easier than it seems to me. I commented the important code to make it easier.

I have the following code in a .js file:

```
$('.delete-answer').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // some actions modifying the tags    
    $('.output').closest('li').remove();
    var idMsg = ...;
    var action = ...;
    var answers = ...;
    $(this).closest('li').children('p').remove();
    $(this).closest('.tr').before('<tr><td><div class="output">Deleting message...</div></td></tr>');
    $(this).closest('.tr').remove();

    // While the servlet is deleting the message, I want to disable the links
    // but I can't, so my problem is just here

    // METHOD 1
    //$('a').unbind('click');

    // METHOD 2
    //$('a').bind('click', function(e){
    //    e.preventDefault();
    //});

    $.post("../app/ForumCampus", {action:action, idMsg:idMsg}, function(data) { 
    });

    // METHOD 1
    //$('a').bind('click');

    // METHOD 2
    //$('a').unbind('click');

    $('.output').empty();
    $('.output').append('Message deleted successfully.');

});
```

And In my HTML I have some list items like these:

```
<li>
    <p class="text">Some text.</p>
    <table class="answer-details" style="width: 100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="tr">
            <td style="width: 50%;">
                <div class="msg-modification" display="inline" align="right">
                    <a id="modify" class="delete-answer" href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>                               
    </tbody>
    </table>
</li>
```

As you can see, I tried two methods to disable the click event:

**Method 1:** I tried the following method: [how to unbind all event using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569393/how-to-unbind-all-event-using-jquery)

Result: It works, unbinding the click event from the anchors with delete-answer class, but:

1) It only deactivate the anchors with delete-answer class. I will prefer to disable **all** links while the servlet is doing it's stuff.

2) I can't (or I don't know how to) re-enable the links.

**Method 2:** I tried the following method: [How do I dynamically enable/disable links with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788946/dynamically-enable-disable-links-w-jquery)

Result: It works for normal anchors, but not for the anchors with class delete-answer.

Both seem incompatible, so I'd **really** appreciate some help.

---

Note: also tried to change the class doing this: `$('.delete-answer').addClass('delete-disabled').removeClass('delete-answer');`

It changes the class and leaves the anchors only with delete-disabled class, but when I click them again, they're still deleting the message and I don't know why :/

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are up to. Try using jsfiddle.net to reproduce your problem, then give us a link to that code.

Comment: @Deele, I'm not familirized with jsfiddle, but I'll take a look. Thanks :)

Comment: @Buitrako: You might also look at http://jsbin.com, which is like jsFiddle but works in a broader range of browsers.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: that's a very interesting and helpful page. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all of that code in a function and use a flag.

1. Add this at the top:

   ```
   (function() {
   ```
2. Add this at the bottom:

   ```
   })();
   ```
3. Just under the top line above, add:

   ```
   // Flag for whether "delete answer" is enabled
   var deleteAnswerEnabled = true;
   ```
4. In your click handler, right at the top:

   ```
   if (!deleteAnswerEnabled) {
       return false;
   }
   ```
5. Change your `post` to:

   ```
   // Disable deleting answers while we're doing it
   deleteAnswerEnabled = false;
   $.post("../app/ForumCampus", {action:action, idMsg:idMsg}, function(data) { 
        // Enable it again now we're done
       deleteAnswerEnabled = true;
   });
   ```

Bringing that all together:

```
// (1)
(function() {
    // (3)
    // Flag for whether "delete answer" is enabled
    var deleteAnswerEnabled = true;


    $('.delete-answer').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // (4)
        // Don't do it if we're disabled
        if (!deleteAnswerEnabled) {
            return false;
        }

        // some actions modifying the tags    
        $('.output').closest('li').remove();
        var idMsg = ...;
        var action = ...;
        var answers = ...;
        $(this).closest('li').children('p').remove();
        $(this).closest('.tr').before('<tr><td><div class="output">Deleting message...</div></td></tr>');
        $(this).closest('.tr').remove();

        // (5)
        // Disable deleting answers while we're doing it
        deleteAnswerEnabled = false;
        $.post("../app/ForumCampus", {action:action, idMsg:idMsg}, function(data) { 
             // Enable it again now we're done
            deleteAnswerEnabled = true;
        });

        $('.output').empty();
        $('.output').append('Message deleted successfully.');

    });
// (2)
})();
```

If you're feeling sufficiently paranoid, you might use a counter rather than a boolean, but the concept is the same.

Comment: You explained your answer very well and it works perfectly. Thank you **very** much! :)

Comment: Only a little comment: your solution disables the .delete-answer anchors, so I made a little modification to disable all links: $('a').click(function(event) { if (!deleteAnswerEnabled) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } });   You can add this to your response if you want. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to do it:

```
$('a').bind('click', false);
```

Comment: I find your answer useful, but with this method the problem is to re-enable the click event later.

Answer (score 1):

Define a separate variable that keeps track of your deleting state:

```
var isDeleting = false; 

$('.delete-answer').click(function(event) {
   if (!isDeleting) {
      isDeleting = true;

      $.post("../app/ForumCampus", {action:action, idMsg:idMsg}, function(data) { 
          isDeleting = false;
      });      
   }
});
```

Also, you don't need an `href` attribute inside the anchor if it doesn't actually contain a URL. Just remove it altogether.

Comment: I didn't understand it either :/   My upvote for you, thanks for your contribution and for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is just .hide() / .show() your click element.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't leave a comment, this is solution for Noob's question on Darm's post ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6815739/2748356)).

I believe the page uses whichever **.bind** was first implemented if two **.binds** are used for the same element. So you have to **.unbind** it first if you want to change the setting from ***FALSE*** to ***TRUE***. To re-enable the click add the latter code to whichever function/event you would want to re-enable it.

**DISABLE**

`$('a').bind('click', true);`

**RE-ENABLE**

```
$('a').unbind('click', false);
$('a').bind('click', true);`
```

***ALSO***, I'm not sure why, setting back to **TRUE** wouldn't work unless I included "jquery-ui.js".

Hope this helps