# Disable a linked element in jQuery and then Enable it later on

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have the following link element on a web page.**How would I disable this using jQuery?** It seems setting the disabled attribute does not disable it.

```
<A style="COLOR: black" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridViewWithLinkqToSQL','Page$20')">20</A>
```

**EDIT 1: ANSWER** (with a fully functional sample page code)

Finally, I was able to enable/disable links. To enable simply attach a click handler in which default action of event is disabled, and  for enabling remove the same click handler. In my code below, Link1 will open yahoo home page, while Link2 will show a javascript error, when both these links are enabled.

Html page  code with necessary javascript/jQuery is as below. Using this approach you can enable/disable multiple hyperlinks within a div ( as in a Grid control). Here's a link to a video that will show a situation in which disabling and enabling links can be very useful: [Disable all hyperlinks within a GridView during AJAX Postback](http://screencast.com/t/wMR9XVeHc). You will notice in the video that when user clicks on column header links or page number links, it doesn't do anything, which is what we want when a long AJAX postback happens and user starts to impatiently click on links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Enable/Disable Links</title>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Link1</a>
        <a style="COLOR: black" href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridViewWithLinkqToSQL','Page$20')">Link2</a>
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Disable Links" onclick="ToggleLinks(true);" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="Enable Links" onclick="ToggleLinks(false);" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ToggleLinks(disabled) {
            var div1 = $('#div1');

           // div1.find("*").prop("disabled", disabled);
            if (disabled) {
                div1.find("a").each(function (i, element) {
                    $(this).click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            }
            else {
                 div1.find("a").each(function (i, e) {
                    $(this).unbind("click");
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The disabled attribute applies to input elements.

Comment: Googling `jquery disable link` gives me dozens of results.

Comment: Have you checked [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970388/jquery-disable-a-link?rq=1) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788946/how-do-i-dynamically-enable-disable-links-with-jquery?rq=1)?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#your_link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g5Mkj/

Answer (score 2):

There is no attribute on a link that you could set to disable it. What you can do is remove it's `href` attribute.

```
$('#yourAnchorId').removeAttr('href');
```

Or you can set a click event on it that cancels the event propagation:

```
$('#yourAnchorId').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note that removing the HREF attribute does the same as preventDefault() but removes the "cursor: pointer" usually on anchors. If you need to remember the HREF attribute, it might be simplier to just "e.preventDefault()"!