# How disable lightbox for some images Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, lightbox

I put a lightbox in a JavaScript file that affects all images, and a little image in the middle of each image.

You click the smaller image to see a bigger version of the image.

My question is, is there a way to turn off LightBox for some images? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGNci.png)

```
lightbox = document.createElement('div')
lightbox.id = 'lightbox' 
document.body.appendChild(lightbox) 

const images document.querySelectorAll('img') images.forEach(image => {
  image.addEventListener('click', e => {
  lightbox.classList.add('active')
  const img = document.createElement('img')
  img.src = image.src
  while(lightbox.firstChild) {
      lightbox.removeChild(lightbox.firstChild)
  }
  lightbox.appendChild(img)

  })})
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313380/disable-lightbox-with-javascript