# disable links, form submit action and modal popups in a cloned object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a site walk-trough on first signup for users. For this I chose to use live elements on the landing view as they appear more customized for each user than pictures. I am using jQuery clone for drawing my live objects to my walk-through modal.

```
   $(".dashboard_content").clone().appendTo( ".t_dashboard_content" );
```

I now need to disable all links, form submit action  and modal popups in the cloned object.Solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788946/how-do-i-dynamically-enable-disable-links-with-jquery) are resulting in target elements on the original elements being disabled also which is undesirable. Any leads to attaining this are welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I dynamically enable/disable links with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788946/how-do-i-dynamically-enable-disable-links-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

you could try to everwrite the link onClick event:

```
$('a').click(function(ev){

        // A global variable you use to enable/disable following links
        if(isLinkDisabled) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                return false;
        }

        return true;

});
```

Comment: I forgot, of course you have to do this on start of your code, when page is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with the following though its slow.

```
     $( ".t_dashboard_content" ).each(function(){
                    //Disable links
                    $("a").attr("href", "#")

                    //Disable form submit
                    $(".search_btn").attr("type", "button");

                    //Disable modal
                    $(".advanced").attr("data-toggle", "");
                });
```